# Python subprocess weird behavior with shell=True on Windows

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess

I am stumped by the shell=True/False toggle behavior of the following python code on Windows:

```
# shell = False   
shell = True

cmd = "ogr2ogr ..."
subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=shell)
```

with appropriate arguments,  the purpose of `cmd` is to call GDAL's *ogr2ogr* to export a postgres table to a shapefile. The ouptut path given to ogr2ogr is an absolute path. In **both** cases, I observe that:

- The code runs with no exceptions.
- `cmd` is syntactically  valid, and an ogr2ogr child process is indeed spawned by python.

However, in the case where `shell=True`, the output shapefile (.shp) is never written to disk, as opposed to when `shell=False`. I would like to find out why.

Comment: Could the expected output file be "written somewhere else?" - eg. what happens if telling ogr2ogr to write to an absolute path?

Comment: good point @user2864740, I am using an absolute path tough (see edit).

Comment: You may be using absolute paths, but we're unable to verify that. Are there any resource files required by `ogr2ogr` that it might not be able to find? The two cases are likely to have different default directories and paths.

Comment: @MarkRansom  if that was the case, wouldn't ogr2ogr throw an error?

Comment: I just noticed you say the *output* path is absolute. What about the *input*?

Comment: The working directory should be the same in both cases. Maybe the command  line contains special shell characters that need to be escaped, such as `&` or `%`. Escaping in CMD can be tricky, and sometimes impossible to get right.